# Multiple ViewControllers with same background

Tags: ios, swift

How can one still background image in multiple view controllers be implemented?

With `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "file.png"))` background would move along with UIViewController while screen switching.

Is it possible to place image on separate layer under view controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Create a class called `MyBackground`:

```
class MyBackground {
   class func addBackgroundImage() {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        UIImage(named: "file")?.drawInRect(self.view.bounds)

        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
    }
}
```

If you want to call it in your `AViewController`, simply call `MyBackground.addBackgroundImage()`

**Solution 2**

Create a ViewController called `MyViewController`:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   addBackgroundImage()
}

func addBackgroundImage() {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
            UIImage(named: "file")?.drawInRect(self.view.bounds)

            let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
        }
}
```

If you AViewController want to set this image, simply do like this:

```
AViewController: MyViewController //AViewController is a subclass of MyViewController
```

For example: I have an image call `background`, and I will set it as a background image of my `ViewController`:

[image]

If I just add it in one line as @startupthekid said:

[image]

If I add it as I said:

[image]

Comment: I have to take some issue with this because why would you ever use a graphics context unnecessarily when you can just do `UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "some-image"))` in one line?

Comment: For the image size. If you don't do this, the image will get it's real size, and when it apply to the simulator screen, will look bad.

Comment: I disagree, I've never had an issue with image size, simulator or otherwise. If you set the `contentMode` and `frame`, you should be fine.

Comment: Are you referring to the differences in retina devices?

Comment: @startupthekid Please check again. Thanks.

Comment: It's 100% that you don't have 1x, 2x, and 3x images. If you don't have those and you try to set the image, it'll look funky. Don't forget, if you do it without the graphics context, you have to set the content mode and the frame/constraints on the image view. But I promise you, it will work.

Comment: If so it will not just add one line as you said: self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "file.png"))

Comment: Incorrect, again. You can set all those properties via a `xib file` and in fact you can make it 0 lines of code if you decide to go that route.

Answer (score 2):

i think you can set background in your container view controllers, such as navi controller, tab controller, then set all your view controller's background to clear color.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the image in `viewDidload` of every `viewController`

Update :

either you should set in every view controller or you can set to windows . Second thing if your background changes dynamically with different images then you can use `prepareforsegue` method to pass images to nextviewcontroller if images are different for each viewcontroller. if same image for every viewcontroller then you can set it to window.

:)

Comment: wouldn't it be moving when i switch to another screen? i need to stay still no matter what.

Comment: Oh you want a permanent static image always in the background? I was under the impression you just wanted the same background. You should clarify your question, it's very unclear what you want in that case. And see my answer, I'll update it.

Comment: @jayåk no it will not move when switch. check my updated answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

A better answer is to use `UIAppearance`. If you're not familiar with it, `UIAppearance` is a proxy protocol that you send messages to and it modifies later instances of that class.

For example if I have a custom button class `RoundButton`:

```
RoundButton.appearance().titleFont = Font.Heavy(20)
```

And in my `RoundButton` class:

```
dynamic var titleFont: UIFont? {
    get { return self.titleLabel?.font }
    set { self.titleLabel?.font = newValue }
}
```

The `dynamic` keywords is incredibly important. It's used for objective-c compatibility and setting properties via `UIAppearance` that don't use it will cause a crash.

You can do as many custom properties as you want and there's a bunch already default in the os.

In your case you can do something like:

```
UIImageView.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([MyCustomViewController.self)].customImage = UIImage(...)
```

You can of course get away with just a custom view controller but in my opinion, `UIApperance` keeps your UI code separate from your controller logic.

One way you could implement the behavior you want is a `UIViewController` subclass:

```
 class MyCustomViewController: UIViewController {
     private let backgroundImageView = UIImageView()

     dynamic var backgroundImage: UIImage? {
         get { self.backgroundImageView.image }
         set { self.backgroundImageView.image = newValue }
     }
 }
```

and then modify the `backgroundImage` property on the appearance instance of `MyCustomViewController`.

```
MyCustomViewController.appearance().backgroundImage = ...
```

EDIT: Given that your question was misleading and that you instead want a shared image that never moves throughout all your view controllers, you can simply insert an image view into the application window:

```
if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "face-mask"))
        window.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.frame = window.bounds
    }
```

If you like Autolayout, like I do, then I'd set constraints to pin the image view to the window edges.